# Paint with the Brush Tool from a light to dark color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, painting, brush-dynamics

I'm seeking for a specific way to use the Brush Tool so that the result be from zero (light color) to dark color. From 0 to 100% color. I want paint hairs but full dark color is a bad idea.

Comment: So you want to paint from grey to a color? Or from 0% opacity to 100% opacity??? What have you tried?

Comment: @Scott i need 0% to 100% opacity please

Answer (score 1):

After choosing a brush, a size, a top and background color, adjust the brush Dynamics: Shape Dynamics and Color Dynamics.

Shape Dynamics > Control > Fade. The quantity depends on you and the brush size

[image: shape]

Color Dynamics > Control > Fade. It goes from top to background color, the same number than the fading on Shape Dynamics.

[image: color]

If you need the brush going to transparent, you should paint over a layer mask with the same brush from black to white. The images below shows the positive and negative version.

This is from black to white over a white mask:

[image: mask]

And this is from white to black over a black mask:

[image: mask 2]

Those are two samples of using this brush for masking:

[image: tiger]

[image: topmodel]

Comment: How, please, is that a general question about graphic deswign, as opposed to a specific questino about the particular software you happen to be using?

Comment: Did you read the tags? I mean, the first tag.

Answer (score 1):

*Without* a drawing/graphic tablet the *best* you can do in terms of **opacity dynamics** is to utilize the **Fade** option in the **Brush Settings**.

Set the `Transfer > Control` to **Fade** then the text field to the right of Fade controls the drop off to transparent. Higher numbers mean longer strokes before the brush is transparent.

[image]

It always start at 100% opacity and then fades to 0% opacity. If you *did* have a drawing/graphic tablet, you could use the Pen Pressure setting, which would dynamically see opacity based upon how hard you press with the stylus. But that's merely not possible without a tablet.